# Pylint no value for argument phrase in method call

Tags: python, django, pylint

I am currently working on my first website, which is a dna to protein translator. What it does is you input a number of letters divisible by three and it gets translated into a protein if the chain exists.

Anyways, this part of the code is working perfectly and I'd even say it looks super pythonic. Right now, I am now working on raising some error messages with the django messages.
Here's the link to the document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/

What I want to do is, when you input a number of letters which isn't divisible by three, i call the message.error to tell that the chain isn't valid.

Here's the code and the method call in case you need it:

```
class TranslatorView(View):
   def build_protein(self, request, phrase):
        protein = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(phrase):
            codon = phrase[i: i + 3]
            amino = self.translate_amino(codon)
            if amino:
                protein.append(amino)
            else:
                print(f"The codon {codon} is not in self.mapper_1")
            i += 3
        if len(phrase) % 3:
            messages.error(request, "INVALID DNA CHAIN")

        return protein
    


    

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'main/translator.html')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phrase = request.POST.get('text', 'translation')
        protein = request.POST.get('text','protein')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'translation': self.translate(phrase), 'protein': ", ".join(self.build_protein(protein))})
```

However, this pylint error appears:

No value for argument 'phrase' in method call (pylint-no-value-for-parameter).

I've been reading about it, and they say you can solve it by disabling the pylint. However, I was hoping for another solution which didn't have to mean disabling pylint.

Perhaps changing something about the method call, I really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to this expression in the last line of your code:

`self.build_protein(protein)`

It is, indeed, missing a value for the "phrase" argument.  You probably want this to be:

`self.build_protein(protein, phrase)`

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try that. Would you please tell me why should I put the phrase parameter in the method call. I don't want to make this error again

Comment: Because you've defined the method as taking two parameters.  I don't really understand what the code is doing, but the way you've written it, that method should have two parameters, `request` and `phrase`.  I assume "protein" is the `request` in this context and that "phrase" is the `phrase`.

Comment: Indeed, the problem has been solved. Now it raises another error, but i'll try to solve it myself. It's a add_message() argument must be an HttpRequest object, not 'str' error.  I'll look it up

Comment: I might suggest starting with some basic Python intro problems before diving into Django... :)

Comment: I did that a long time ago before diving into django. However, despite being written in python, I'd say django is a place full of new things and it's difficult to keep up for a django begginer.

Comment: The stuff you're running into is pretty universal "how Python functions work" stuff and isn't particular to Django, but the extra complexities of Django might make it harder to debug than it otherwise would be.